# Python 3 Formatting Lists in accordance to PEP8

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, formatting, pep8

I am working with severals lists that are hundreds of objects long and I have to format them correctly for work. Is there a simple loop that can take the my list and format it  in accordance to PEP8.

PEP8 limits all lines to a maximum of 79 characters. What is the best way to accomplish this without breaking off a string midway but still conforming to this rule?

We can use the list below as an example. I usually get a random output of stings that I format into list but they are continuous and I spend hours conforming them to the 79 character rule.

```
List = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','string','bean','bling','bling', 'beep', 'boop', 'steep', 'stoop', 'Amberlance', 'you', 'get','my', 'point', ',', 'right', '?']
```

Comment: Are you saying that you want to format it into a string?

Comment: Let a code formatter do the work for you. I like [`black`](https://black.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and [`yapf`](https://github.com/google/yapf).

Comment: @JohnIson No, I mean I take a string and turn them into lists. The list tend to be way too long. I would like to format the list to not exceed the 79 character limit as per PEP8. I am wondering if I can create a script that can text wrap for these lists after a certain character count and if so how.

Comment: @jakub I have not used these I will check them out.

Comment: "severals lists that are hundreds of objects long" Why are these in python source code and not some external data file such as a JSON?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pprint` module. The module provides a capability to “pretty-print” arbitrary Python data structures in a form which can be used as input to the interpreter. Is this what you are looking for -

```py
import pprint

myList = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','string','bean','bling','bling', 'beep', 'boop', 'steep', 'stoop', 'Amberlance', 'you', 'get','my', 'point', ',', 'right', '?']
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
pp.pprint(myList)
```

**Output**

```sh
[   '1',
    '2',
    '3',
    '4',
    '5',
    '6',
    '7',
    'string',
    'bean',
    'bling',
    'bling',
    'beep',
    'boop',
    'steep',
    'stoop',
    'Amberlance',
    'you',
    'get',
    'my',
    'point',
    ',',
    'right',
    '?']
```

Or if you want to print 79 characters of the list in one line, then -

```py
import pprint

myList = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','string','bean','bling','bling', 'beep', 'boop', 'steep', 'stoop', 'Amberlance', 'you', 'get','my', 'point', ',', 'right', '?']
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(width=79, compact=True)
pp.pprint(myList)
```

**Output**

```sh
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 'string', 'bean', 'bling', 'bling', 'beep',
 'boop', 'steep', 'stoop', 'Amberlance', 'you', 'get', 'my', 'point', ',',
 'right', '?']
```

Comment: That's not what I would consider "pretty", it sacrifices a lot of vertical space just to keep items one per line.

Comment: Thanks @MarkRansom for pointing that out. I have updated the answer according to the review..!!

Comment: It's too bad you can't line the items up in columns.

Comment: The second is the one I needed. Thanks chaps. It makes these lists way more digestible. Thank you.